# image uncenters when browser expands

Tags: html, css

For some reason my image is centered when the browser width is less than 1015px width-wise, but when I go over that it moves completely to the left, with no padding against the side of the page. I'm doing:

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="../index.html"><img src="../img/logo.png" alt="logo" style="height:100px; width:100px;" /></a>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="" style="color: white; border-bottom: 2px solid white;">How It Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="../portfolio/index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="../team/index.html">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="../contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="../jobs/index.html">Jobs</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<img class="center" src="../img/laptop.png" alt="laptop-pic" style="height:500px; width:500px;" />
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 60px;
    bottom: 30px;
}

#nav li {
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.canvas-wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}

img.center {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

**Edit**

The problem is somewhere in the markup/styling of my navigation bar. When I remove the markup for the navigation bar, it centers correctly. I've edited the question to include the HTML and CSS for the nav bar. I don't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I don't see anything that could cause this... can you recreate the problem in a jsfiddle or post more of your CSS?

Comment: Working fine on here: http://jsfiddle.net/Oceanity/bjy7x071/  What are the styles on the parent object?

Comment: @Oceanity it is enclosed in a div called canvas-wrap which has the above styling. Very strange. It seems to not center at all in Firefox.

Comment: I feel like the culprit is most likely a media query that is somehow causing the image or one of the parent divs to become an inline-block or a float: left which would break the margin centering.  When you use the inspector on the image, are the margin-left and margin-right styles still active or are they disabled?

Comment: @Oceanity it seems that they are still active, even when the image is pushed all the way to the left instead of being centered.

Comment: @Oceanity when I remove the CSS snippet: #nav ul {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 60px;
    bottom: 30px;
} it works. Is this the source of the problem? Specifically when I remove the line float: right;

Comment: The float right may be causing issues with the image, although with that hierarchy I feel like it probably shouldn't, perhaps try this on the image: http://jsfiddle.net/Oceanity/bjy7x071/1/  You can also add a "width: 100%" on the centered-image container to force it even more.

Comment: I don't find any problems. Here is a codepen illustration of what I see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwZXEK

Comment: Hi Apollo, there are a number of issues with your CSS. Take a look at my solution below - I hope something helps. I tried to be a big thorough. Good luck with getting it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an issue when viewing in Firefox. Your markup and CSS however are very simplistic. I assume this is only because you don't want to post your entire solution here.

What you may want to consider is adding a clearfix just before the closing #nav in the markup. As in the following:

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="logo">
    <a href="#../index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" style="height:100px; width:100px;" /></a>
</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="" style="color: white; border-bottom: 2px solid white;">How It Works</a></li>
    <li><a href="#../portfolio/index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#../team/index.html">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#../contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#../jobs/index.html">Jobs</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

The CSS for the clear needs the absolute basics, although you can make your clearfix as complex as you wish:

```
.clear { clear: both; }
```

You can also add overflow as an option to your #nav, but this is definitely not advised for a container holding a navigation because it will hide items like subnavs. But to add the overflow: hidden, you do the following:

```
#nav {
margin-bottom: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

What I would do with your .center image is remove the inline styling, and then do the following with the CSS declaration/and HTML markup:

```
<img class="center" src="img/laptop.png" alt="laptop-pic" style="" />


img.center {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%; /* For responsive */
max-width: 500px; /* For responsive */
height: auto; /* For responsive */
}
```

Your inline-block for `#nav ul li` will not work because you've applied `float: right` to `#nav ul`. You also have `right: 60px` within the same `ul` declaration. If your intent is inline-block for the `li` elements, you need to remove the aforementioned.

The final thing I'll mention in my response is your use of display: inline-block; Make sure that you remove whitespace from this. There are several methods upon how to do this - none of which are pretty. You can't really remove the whitespace with CSS, so the best approach is to fix it in the markup. Below are 2 solutions of many:

Solution 1 for inline-block:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" style="color: white; border-bottom: 2px solid white;">How It Works</a></li
    ><li><a href="#../portfolio/index.html">Portfolio</a></li
    ><li><a href="#../team/index.html">Team</a></li
    ><li><a href="#../contact/index.html">Contact</a></li
    ><li><a href="#../jobs/index.html">Jobs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Solution 2 for inline-block:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" style="color: white; border-bottom: 2px solid white;">How It Works</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#../portfolio/index.html">Portfolio</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#../team/index.html">Team</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#../contact/index.html">Contact</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#../jobs/index.html">Jobs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And since I see no browser reset, you may want to add `margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type` to `#nav > ul` and `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to `#nav > ul > li`. Then apply your styles to the anchor tag within the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which browser you're using. When I run your code on Chrome everything works fine, but IE is no good.
I'm thinking this is related to a known problem about IE not rendering `display: block` and `display: inline-block` correctly.

I did a different approach to get it done. Just wrapped the image with a div and centered the contents. Its not the more elegant answer though.

See below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="divCenter">
   <img src="../img/laptop.png" alt="laptop-pic" style="height:500px; width:500px;" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divCenter {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```